# Creating unique post-back addresses to receive responses to POST submissions via PHP

Tags: php, web-applications

I know this is a fundamental understanding problem, but as a novice I would love if someone would be willing to clarify this for me.

Right now, my site works for a single user, me. The answer comes in to a reply.php page, where I parse and save the data to my database.

For multiple users, my readings point to having to use "Sessions", where each session can set a UserID and other useful, personalized information stored in a cookie.

My question is:  can I use a unique identifier such as session data to create a unique address for that user to be redirected to? If not, what do I use?

I saw an example online indicating something like `www.site.com/replies/dfb97g` or `www.site.com/replies.php?dfb97g

I'd like a clarification on how to proceed.

Comment: you wouldn't; you'd use session to indicate what the correct content to output is. But you can do what you ask if you can provide a good reason to do so.

Comment: You mentioned this being a response to POST in your title. Was it something you wanted to be incorporated in an answer?

Comment: You can also create dynamic pages using $GET, using datas got from the $SESSION, like your www.site.com/replies.php?SESSIONDATAHERE IE USERID. Some on one page, you use the session data to create the URL in a link to a dynamic page, then on the dynamic page you use $GET to use the data and display the correct content. You can add validation in the database if you want only them to use by checking session user ID or IP, etc.   Using some nifty coding you can automatically create a html page for the user and redirect them to this in the link, like the 'www.site.com/replies/SESSIONDATAHERE USERID

Comment: Don't pass anything user specific over the url, that's what sessions are meant for. Just ask for the userID from the session (that means your user is authenticated) and use that userID to process the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no sense to do this...

**Using SESSION and GET**

User completes a form which posts to `reply.php`

reply.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['userid'] = strtotime('now'); # don't use this as a user id, it's just an example

#add something to db using generated userid

header("location: replies.php?userid=".$_SESSION['userid']);
?>
```

replies.php

```
<?php
#session_start(); don't even need it

# get something from db where userid=".$_GET['userid'];

# output something
?>
```

**Using SESSION normally**

User completes a form which posts to `reply.php`

reply.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['userid'] = strtotime('now'); # don't use this as a user id, it's just an example

#add something to db using generated userid

header("location: replies.php");
?>
```

replies.php

```
<?php
session_start(); 

# get something from db where userid=".$_SESSION['userid'];

# output something
?>
```

There's no need to pass the variable when you have it in session.

Answer (score -1):

So you are correct, sessions will help you here. The easiest way for me to explain would be for me to give you a code example.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    $_SESSION['userid'] = rand();
  }
  echo "Hello User ".$_SESSION['userid']."<br/>\n";
  echo "Custom URL: http://www.example.com/replies.php?".$_SESSION['userid']."<br/>\n";
?>
```

`[session_unset()][1]` and `[session_destroy()][2]` are some useful functions you will need to use as well. You will need to use `session_start()` before you use any of them!

Let me know if you have any questions. Good luck!

Comment: might be useful to add how he/she would use that query string to provide the content for just that user.

Comment: popnoodles, have anything to say about this?

Comment: If you're using sessions, you wouldn't actually need the custom URL... Just read the session variable in the replies.php file.

Comment: So then which URL do I specify in the POST query to send the answer back to?

Comment: The URL that reads the session variable and gets relevant content.

Comment: No need and rather bad idea passing the userID via url. The session knows it!

Comment: Pretend you are coding for just ONE user. PHP and Apache (your webserver) will handle the rest. Use sessions to generate custom data for a specific user, that is all you need to worry about.